# how to create a common menu for an android application

Tags: android

For an android application I need to have a single menu in common that can be displayed on every screen with its structure and functionality written in another class or activity that can be used in all other activities.

Answer (score 3):

Create baseClass Activity. There you can implement the menu structure. After that each activity extends this baseClass activity.

Comment: For implementation details See this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14922375/1927845

Answer (score 0):

Create a MainActivity which extends **ActivityGroup** class  and all other activity as its sub activities . Use **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)** method to addmenu item in MainActivity.
All the other activity can show that menu items automatically.

see this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityGroup {

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        menu.add("1");
        menu.add("2");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //start other activity here
    }
}
```

Hope this will give you some idea on the issue.

Comment: @ Dinesh: can you send me a sample of that...??